MissingPluginException when using Flutter module as AAR in native Android project
I have a Flutter module that communicates with native Android code using MethodChannel. When I run the Flutter module independently, everything works fine and the native code is called correctly.
However, when I build the Flutter module as an AAR and use it in my other/different native Android project, I encounter the following exception when trying to open the module and then calling the module function to get a response from the native:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getMessagefromnative on channel java-code-use/flutter)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MyHomePageState.getMsg (package:flutter_module/main.dart:125:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_module/main.dart:177:10)
<asynchronous suspension>

This exception occurs only when I open the Flutter module from my native Android project. It works fine when running the Flutter module on its own.
